# Graphene: What are the Difference between serializer, parse_literal and parse_value staticmethods on Custom Scalar?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

Currently the documentation in `Graphene-Python` on `Custom Scalar` does not provide proper context on how these methods are called, or atleast what are the difference between these staticmethods?

I can see that each method intends to display the object. Well on `serializer` method this is pretty straightforward.

All method accept argument and display value. As for me a beginner I could not comprehend how to use this method properly.

```
class DateTime(Scalar):
    '''DateTime Scalar Description'''

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(dt):
        # omitted

    @staticmethod
    def parse_literal(node):
        # omitted

    @staticmethod
    def parse_value(value):
        # omitted
```

It would be nice to have a proper explanation or context on how to use these methods.

Hopefully some of you could share knowledge and enlighten us how to implement custom scalar.